# Get any user by SessionID (cookie) from Devise authentication system

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, devise, sessionid

A JavaScript piece of code sends UserId when initializing WebSockets connection. This requires to pass UserId from Rails view to JavaScript source.

I do not like this solution for two reasons:

- I want JS code to be entirely in `*.js` file without having to include it as partial into layouts
- UserId is easy to counterfeit and listen messages addressed to other user

The better solution is obvious: in any case each WebSocket connection from an authenticated user is accompanied by Devise's SessionID in cookie. I already found how to extract this cookie from handshake data and now there is one problem:

The WebSockets listener is running constantly in a background thread whether some user is authenticated or not. So, it does not have an access to user's session.

The question:

How to get an user or UserId by SessionID if I am not authenticated. Does Devise have some SessionID storage in memory which I could access (probably with some nasty hack).

Answer (score 0):

Devise stores stuff by warden within the user session. So if you have no access to the session, there is also none to the user_id within this separate thread.

Since your are exposing the user_id anyway in the script, you can just set it into an additional cookie.

You could also implement an api enpoint returning the id.

You can render it into the page within some invisible 'data-' attribute

```
<body data-user-id='asfasdfeefifpf'> ... </body>.
```

Or at least you could just keep the code in the js partial, which sets the id and extract the lib code into separate file.

```
 <%= javascript_tag do %>
   window.user_id = '<%= j current_user.id %>';
 <% end %>
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript?view=asciicast

Comment: `Since your are exposing the user_id anyway in the script` - I do not want to do so.

Comment: There is no problem with that at all, as long as this id is not an incremented number. Just ad some uuid or unique user token to your user model and expose this